# iOSアプリをつくりはじめる場合に、ペーパープロトタイピング以外に、正式な設計手法はありますか？

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, 詳細設計

iOSアプリをつくりはじめる場合に、
ペーパープロトタイピング以外に、
正式というか、一般的に使われている設計手法は何かありますか？

（そもそもはじめに「設計」という行為をするのが正しいかどうかもわかりません）

知りたいのは、アプリをつくる際の正式な手順・方法、実務で行なわれている方法です。

私は、ホビープログラマーでして、思いついたアイデアをいきなりストーリーボードでつくっていくという方法でやっていますが、のちのち不具合を生むことになったり、結局トータルで考えると、開発効率が悪くなったりする気もします。

一般的な質問となってしまいますが、
ヒントだけでもいただけますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

正式なとかこれがルールとかはないんじゃないでしょうか？自分なりの方法を模索すれば良いと思います。

私は仕事でアプリの受託開発をしていますが、デザインはデザイン会社さんに発注して細かく決めてもらうことがあったり、こちらから提案するような形でガッと実装してみたり、デザイン会社さんの人に来てもらって一緒に試行錯誤したり、いろいろです。

個人でやる時には、[Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com)を使ったり、Keynoteを使ったりします。最近の体験では、Sketchで先にレイアウトを固めてしまうのが手戻りがなく効率が良かったです。ボタンなどそのまま画像としてExportできたりしてとても便利でした。

プロトタイピングツールについては、よくまとまっている記事を見つけました。ご存知かもしれませんが一応。
http://qiita.com/usagimaru/items/b5485589550787820348

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。自分流でも大丈夫なんですね。Sketch参考になりました！プロトタイピングツールについてもこんなにあるとは知らなかったです。私は今まで個人でアプリをつくっていたのですが、今プログラマーの仕事を探しておりまして、先日の面接では、開発の手法が我流であり、正式な設計スキルが低いということで通らなかったのです。それで、実務では何か一般的に行われている方法論があるのかと思いまして、調べてみようと思っているところです。